Email service error SMTP Error (454): Connection to server failed, virtualmin panel
I have error with SMTP setup with roundcube.
When i send the message this message show to me:
SMTP Error (454): Connection to server failed
I checked every things like:

check the config.inc.php for roundcube SMTP setup here:

$config['imap_host'] = 'localhost:143';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'tls://localhost'; // once i insert this tls://mydomain.tld
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
$config['support_url'] = '';
note: i change tls:// to ssl://
this error shown to me:
SMTP Error (): Connection to server failed.


checked the postfix.cf, everything is correct, here:

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = isv.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, isv.mydomain.com, localhost.mydomain.com, localhost
#relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dependent
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
smtp_host_lookup = dns
allow_percent_hack = no
resolve_dequoted_address = no
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sni_map
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/postfix.ca.pm

try to setup over outlook it is working fine but the received emails didn't work.
I sent email to Gmail and Outlook but when i reply to my email not working.

The information are incomplete. Nothing indicates that postfix is even running on localhost:465. No logs are provided from Postfix which might indicate a problem. Additionally port 465 is for implicit TLS so it should be ssl:// (implicit TLS) not tls:// (explicit with STARTTLS) in the config. As for comparison with outlook - it does not help to say that it works if you don't also say how it is configured.

Becuase there are issue when using ssl for new virtualmin config im using TLS and running for 2 or more in another servers.

Now Im fixed this and resolved issue, it was because of SSL cert not setup correctly, i removed it and re-create via Let's.. The errors now for delivery email it is not working i will send the screens and all the information to see why it is not running via my config
